# How do I update every title of a certain category with a phrase

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add "custom built" to the front of every product title in a certain category.

```
<?php 
$args = array('post_type' => 'product',
              'tax_query'=> array(
             array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                   'field'    => 'id',
                   'terms'    => '3439',),),
              'posts_per_page'    => -1,
         );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
   {
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
         $prod_id = get_the_ID();
         $my_post = array('ID'=> $prod_id,
                          'post_title'   => 'custom built', // I want to add 'custom built' not replace the whole title
              );
         wp_update_post( $my_post );
      endwhile;
   }
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: You can use `'post_title' => 'custom built ' . get_the_title()`. Or you could use a *filter* without statically changing the post title.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a filter. Sometimes things change and strings have to be translated and so on:

```
function my_custom_built_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    $post  = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( 'product' == $post->post_type ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', [ 'fields' => 'ids' ] );
        if ( in_array( '3439', $terms ) ) {
            $title = 'Custom build ' . $title;
        }
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_custom_built_title', 10, 2 );
```

I did not test it but it could be a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, you can add it simply with CSS `::after` . You can add this:

```
.product-title::after{
    content:'custom built';
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}

.product-title{
    position:relative;
}
```

Just replace `.product-title` with the class of your title.

Comment: I'm sure the OP wants the title be visible in the source code, and not just visually.

Comment: How can you be sure of that, he didn't mention anything relevant to it.

Comment: You're right @dominotrix (and +1 for that), and I'm sorry about the "I'm sure" part, which should've been "I think".

Comment: Thats an interesting option but not really what I'm looking for